# My sql syntax error 1064 -can't find what is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I go this error message when I run this query

```
SELECT name,state FROM customers WHERE state ‌IN ('CA','NC','NY')
```

Error
SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT name, state
FROM customers
WHERE state ‌IN(

'CA',  'NC',  'NY'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'â€Œin ('CA','NC','NY') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

I has a look there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html but I still can't find the reason why

Thank you

Comment: The 1064 error should be followed by "near <some character>"... which points to exactly what is causing a problem (in most cases)

Comment: The error is the `=` at `state IN =(...)`  Should just be `state IN (...)`

Comment: If you edited it and still receive an error from that query (which is syntactically valid) you must post the full error, _and_ any other surrounding code, such as if you attempted to execute 2 queries at once...

Comment: There is the full error, its the same as above

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT name, state
FROM customers
WHERE state ‌in(

'CA',  'NC',  'NY'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'â€Œin ('CA','NC','NY')
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1 


thats why I dont understand, the query looks ok

Comment: the command is SELECT name,state FROM customers WHERE state ‌in ('CA','NC','NY')

Comment: `near 'â€Œin` There you have it... What looks like plain whitespace on your screen is actually some non-printable character. Delete the space there and retype it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `=` after `IN`

```
SELECT name, state FROM customers 
WHERE state ‌IN ('CA','NC','NY')
```

Comment: sorry, I had initially removed the = after in.I just added it to see if that solved the issue.Without the =  sign, I still have the same issue.Thank you

Comment: You habe a special character in your query. Retype it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,state FROM customers WHERE state ‌IN ('CA','NC','NY')
```

You can not use the '=' with an IN

Comment: Not _"don't have to"_, but rather _"cannot"_.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy your query and run it in MySQL

You have some strange "hidden" character before IN

If you delete it, then everything works fine